# AFNetworking 2.0 and AFPropertylist

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking-2

I have tried to migrate my app to iOS 7 and therefore i have to use AFNetworking 2.0.

When I use this code:

```
NSURL *plistURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/test.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:plistURL];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
        [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFPropertyListRequestSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id propertyList) {

//some code

 }failure:nil];

[operation start];
```

}

I get a warning and while compiling an error:
Warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'AFHTTPResponseSerializer<AFURLResponseSerialization> *' from 'AFPropertyListRequestSerializer *'
```

error:

```
AFPropertyListRequestSerializer responseObjectForResponse:data:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdd83160
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'AFHTTPResponseSerializer *' from 'AFPropertyListRequestSerializer *'

The error is pretty clear. You are assigning a **request** serializer to a **response** serializer and, of course, it doesn't work.

You probably want to use a `AFPropertyListResponseSerializer` instead.

Comment: thank you. Error and Warning are gone. the only issue now is, that now the ActivityIndicator spins endlessly and no plist is loaded. It even does not show up a NSLog right after code id propertyList) { code in the console.

Comment: you are welcome. The issue you are facing seems to fall beyond the scope of this question. You may try to start the operation with `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];` as opposed to call `start`, but I think you should post another more specific question.